# How can I extract decision tree's node in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to extract my decision tree's detail information like threshold, gini...

Answer (score 1):

You can export decision tree in [dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29) format, and do whatever you want with it, no one forces you to visualize it:
[Link with source code from official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.export_graphviz.html#sklearn.tree.export_graphviz)

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

with open("iris.dot", 'w') as f:
    f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)
```

iris.dot file now contains:

```
digraph Tree {
node [shape=box] ;
0 [label="X[3] <= 0.8\ngini = 0.6667\nsamples = 150\nvalue = [50, 50, 50]"] ;
1 [label="gini = 0.0\nsamples = 50\nvalue = [50, 0, 0]"] ;
0 -> 1 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=45, headlabel="True"] ;
2 [label="X[3] <= 1.75\ngini = 0.5\nsamples = 100\nvalue = [0, 50, 50]"] ;
0 -> 2 [labeldistance=2.5, labelangle=-45, headlabel="False"] ;
3 [label="X[2] <= 4.95\ngini = 0.168\nsamples = 54\nvalue = [0, 49, 5]"] ;
2 -> 3 ;
....
}
```